# Why Don't we Say Tachanun on a Particular Day?

Tags: tefilla, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, tachanun

There are many days on which we don't say Tachanun, and much argument about whether we say it on any given day -- but is there any underlying reason why we wouldn't say it, a reason which might explain why we do or don't say it on a given day?

I looked in the Rambam and the M"B and all I saw was lists of when we do and don't say it -- no reasoning behind why. There were some explorations of why a specific day might be excluded, but no generalizable rule through which I could then predict whether on another  day we would say Tachanun.

Is there a rule which determines saying or not saying Tachanun, or is the entire practice a series of individual cases with separate logic for each?

---

<sub>[A similar question, but about Tu Bishvat specifically.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13998/why-is-there-no-tachanun-on-tu-bshvat)</sub>

Comment: Nearly all the days are celebratory occasions and nearly all celebratory occasions omit Tachanun. That's seems pretty apparent from the lists.

Comment: Is a yahrzeit then a celebratory day? (the reason in the M"B about a wedding day spoke more about justice than a contradiction in content)

Comment: I guess ask someone who omits Tachanun on a Yahrtzeit. Note every day is a Yahrtzeit of a prophet, given that there were 1200000 of them (Megilla 15a). Doesn't seem to be the traditional Jewish practice to omit it on a Yahrtzeit, given that Tachanun was still recited in the days of the Talmud.

Comment: It's not exactly ALL celebratory days. We omit it on Tish'a B'Av as well, and this is not exactly a "celebration". OTOH, it has its own reason, b/c it is called a "Yom Tov", so in a sense, it follows the others. However, note that we omit Tachanun in a mourner's home. My rabbi explained that Tachanun has a "two-sided" omission rule. Either very happy occasions and very sad occasions.

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand the math (you said it very well in another post about the infinitesimal odds that no one died on a certain day) but I'm wondering if there is something inherent in the content which makes it inappropriate to a particular type of day across the board.

Comment: @DanF that 2 value rule is what confuses me. I wonder if there are other examples of such two-sided applications of halacha (maybe for a different question).

Comment: @DanF I didn't say "exactly all celebratory days".

Comment: while tisha b'av is currently a day of mourning it is interestingly still called a "moed". In the times of moshiach when the beis hamikdash is rebuilt will become a yontiff of simcha. Additionally there are sources that talk of tish b'av as the day when moshiach will be born. There are both aspects of mourning and well  as reasons to be hopeful and not completely sad on this day.

Comment: @Dude it's not so interesting. Moed is not a positive or negative term. It just means "occasion". There are happy and sad occasions.

Answer (score 1):

R Reuven Slater wrote [a very interesting book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568714394) on the background and explanation of *Tachanun*. He answers your question as such

- Generally speaking **we not recite *Tachanun* on days that reflect festivity**
- We don't say *Tachanun* on Tisha b'Av as it will one day be a day of great joy marking the arrival of the Messianic area - others say because we are like *aveilim* on Tisha B’Av (see below) or because it is called a Yom Tov (see [here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Vol9Issue12.pdf), p. 16)
- We don't say *Tachanun* in the presence of a *hatan* or *baal ha'brit* (father, sandak, mohel) because of their joy
- We don't recite *Tachanun* on minha from day before, the same way an *avel* (mourner) interrupts his *aveilut* on Friday afternoon daytime (thus showing the time of *simcha* begins before nightfall) - *Tachanun* shares some features of aveilus because of its serious and somber nature
- *Tachanun* is not recited in a house of mourning, because *aveilut* represents darkness, a time for strict judgement. Reciting *Tachanun* highlights our faults which may in turn cause Hashem to deal with us more harshly. Others say that *aveilut* is comparable to Yom Tov (see [here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Vol9Issue12.pdf), p. 3, note 2)

On whether or not to skip Tachanun on yahrzeits, in the introduction of the book, R Yisroel Reisman brings the [Minchas Elazar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Elazar_Spira) (the Chassidic leader of pre-war Munkatz)

> Regarding *Tachanun* - the custom of people, who call themselves
>   chassidim, is to be lenient. This is without merit and deserves
>   ridicule. Their contention that [*tachanun* be skipped] due to a
>   *yahrzeit* is laughable and causes pain to the heart. There is no day
>   which is not the *yahrzeit* of thousands, perhaps tens of thousands of
>   great, righteous men... (Divrei Torah 3:83)

I think this covers all cases mentioned above in the comments.

For further references see also [Halachically Speaking vol. 9 issue 12](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Vol9Issue12.pdf)

Comment: so his explanation is "happy days and also some sad days"?

Comment: @Danno his answer is "days of festivity or with people of festivity (hatan, brit mila) incl Tisha bAv" with a special situation for a bet avel

Comment: So why not skip Tachanun during the (happy) month of Adar?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin maybe we learn from this that Adar is not as joyous as Nissan ?