# Skipping Tachanun - Difference between Chattan vs. Avel

Tags: mourning-aveilus, brit-milah, tachanun, chassan-groom

[This M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68245/5275) says that if a *Chattan* is in shul, *tachanun* is skipped.

Art Scroll and Birnbaum Siddurim say that Tachanun is skipped in the house of a mourner. However, if the mourner is in shul, *tachanun* is still said.

What is the difference between a mourner being in shul vs. a chattan being there that causes the entire shul to skip / not skip tachanun? WHy shouldn't they have the same rule for both?

It seems that there is already a precedence not to say Tachanun in the presence of a mourner, but its restricted to when you are praying in his home. But when he comes to shul, his presence has no effect on tachanun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[M.B.131:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=23) The mourner is under the influence of Strict Justice, and always omits tachanun so as not to strengthen its effect.
Visitors to the shivah would be subject to that influence, or at least do not wish to strengthen its effect on the mourner, whose home it is.
In shul, other people's prayers would not be specifically attached to the mourner. The mourner himself can leave the room during tachanun.

Comment: Dov. Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Your answer is similar to mine. I prefer giving you a "gift", as I answered my own question, here. I shall make some edits to your question and delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Ba'er Hetev on O.C. 131 #11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=24) explains that since a chattan is immersed in his joy and he is considered important, his joy affects the entire congregation. However, when an aveil enters the shul, we don't want to intensify G-d's attribute of judgement, and also, not everyone in the shul is in mourning.