# Tachanun on a King / President visiting a city

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, synagogue, tachanun

Would Synagogues say Tachanun when a King or President comes to visit a city or perhaps comes to visit a Synagogue? I couldn’t see anything in Orach Chaim dealing with this issue.

Comment: This question is at least relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68204/why-dont-we-say-tachanun-on-a-particular-day

Comment: If there were a reason not to say Tachanun in the presence of a King or President, SO would surely have mentioned it. Why would you think they should cause it to be omitted?

Comment: No one where I live does not say tachanun when the president is in town.